# Vb + Custom Url String UTF-8

Tags: vb.net, url, utf-8

I have an url to **scrape** some products.
But the url have a strange symbol :

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=✓&q=daredevil+sideshow&commit=Go
```

When i put it on my vb net code i have :

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=daredevil+sideshow&commit=Go
```

And i cant find my products

## 1 try :

```
Dim s1 = $"https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=✓&q={productsearch}+{brandsearch}&commit=Go"
```

Result is :

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=✓&q=+&commit=Go
```

## 2 try :

```
Dim s1 = $"https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q={productsearch}+{brandsearch}&commit=Go"
```

Result is :

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=+&commit=Go
```

This is my current code:

```
        'find product
        Dim productsearch = TextBox4.Text 'Product name
        Dim brandsearch = ComboBox1.Text 'Branch Product
        Dim s1 = $"https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q={productsearch}+{brandsearch}&commit=Go" 'Url Search with Strings
        TextBox5.Text = s1 'Result
        'find product
```

I need Return Like :

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=daredevil+sideshow&commit=Go
```

or

```
https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=✓&q=daredevil+sideshow&commit=Go
```

Why i have that ?

Comment: URLs do not support un-encoded Unicode characters, only ASCII characters. So `✓` cannot appear un-encoded in a URL, it must be charset-encoded to bytes and then those bytes url-encoded in `%HH` hex format. `%E2%9C%93` is the url-encoded UTF-8 form of `✓`.  In a browser UI, you can type in `✓` and it will be encoded to `%E2%9C%93` when transmitted to the web server.  This is a common trick sites use to detect if a browser supports Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

Done

```
'Dim encoded = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/白雜訊")
    Dim productsearch = TextBox4.Text 'Product name
    Dim brandsearch = ComboBox1.Text 'Branch Product
    'Dim s1 = $"https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q={productsearch}+{brandsearch}&commit=Go" 'Url Search with Strings
    Dim s1 = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode($"https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=✓&q={productsearch}+{brandsearch}&commit=Go") 'Url Search with Strings
    TextBox5.Text = s1 'Result
    'find product
```